# React native cors

Tags: express, react-native, cors

Tengo un proyecto de react native el cual manda a una api externa la informacion que tomo de los TextInputs, el proceso de envio lo hace correctamente pero tengo un problema, dado que la peticion no proviene de otro dominio o url, como podria configurar mis cors de mi api para que solo react native pueda llamara a esa api y no haya vulnerabilidades de otros dominios o algun problema de ese tipo, la api es en express con typescript, o cual es la logica a aplicar en esta situación (ya que no debería de dejar acceso a cualquier persona para llamara  a la api).

He pensado en usar cabeceras y enviar información la cual la api reciba y contenga la informacion necesaria que confirme que se envio desde react native o un celular cualquiera, alguna otra idea o solucion?